# Strip html tags out of AMP Article (Wordpress)

Tags: html, regex, wordpress, strip, amp-html

I installed the amp plugin on my Wordpress site.
Now I want to customize the output of the `post_amp_content` in order to fulfill everything to have no errors, if I use the AMP-Validator.

The current problem is that in my normal Wordpress posts I use the picture tag. `<picture>` and `</picture>` but these are not allowed.

So now I want to go into the content which is provided to the AMP plugin:

```
<!doctype html>
<html amp>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <?php do_action( 'amp_post_template_head', $this ); ?>

    <style amp-custom>
    <?php $this->load_parts( array( 'style' ) ); ?>
    <?php do_action( 'amp_post_template_css', $this ); ?>
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="amp-wp-title-bar">
    <div>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $this->get( 'home_url' ) ); ?>">
        <?php $site_icon_url = $this->get( 'site_icon_url' ); ?>
        <?php if ( $site_icon_url ) : ?>
            <amp-img src="<?php echo esc_url( $site_icon_url ); ?>" width="32" height="32" class="amp-wp-site-icon"></amp-img>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php echo esc_html( $this->get( 'blog_name' ) ); ?>
    </a>
</div>
</nav>
<div class="amp-wp-content">
    <h1 class="amp-wp-title"><?php echo wp_kses_data( $this->get( 'post_title' ) ); ?></h1>
    <ul class="amp-wp-meta">
        <?php $this->load_parts( apply_filters( 'amp_post_template_meta_parts', array( 'meta-author', 'meta-time', 'meta-taxonomy' ) ) ); ?>
    </ul>
    <?php echo $this->get( 'post_amp_content' ); // amphtml content; no kses ?>
</div>
<?php do_action( 'amp_post_template_footer', $this ); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

The content is get with `$this->get( 'post_amp_content' );`
Here I want to strip the `<picutre>` and `</picture>` tags.

My approach was this:

```
<?php 
$content =get( 'post_amp_content' );
$content = preg_replace("/<picture[^>]+\>/i", "", $content);
$content = apply_filters('post_amp_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content);
echo $this-> $content; // amphtml content; no kses ?>
```

but it is not working. I am pretty new to this, Where did I do my mistake?

Comment: FYI: If your content is Unicode you need to use `/u` with `preg_replace` regex (`preg_replace("/<picture[^>]+>/ui", "", $content);`)

Comment: In here: `preg_replace("/<picture[^>]+\>/i", "", $content);`, you are matching all characters that are not `>` and removing them with the regex `[^>]+`, which means anything that isn't `>` at least once.